# PowerShell to get Azure API report?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-api-management

Using the PowerShell below, How can I create the report in a .CSV format for all APIs under my Azure Tenant ?

I tried using the below, as a Global Admin account, but it still failed.

```
Get-AzApiManagement

$Context = Get-AzContext

Get-AzApiManagementBackend -Context $Context
Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $Context
Get-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $Context
```

Error:

```
Get-AzApiManagementBackend : Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext" value of type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Models.PsApiManagementContext".
At line:3 char:37
+ Get-AzApiManagementBackend -Context $Context
+                                     ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzApiManagementBackend], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.GetAzureApiManagementBackend
 
Get-AzApiManagementProduct : Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext" value of type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Models.PsApiManagementContext".
At line:4 char:37
+ Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $Context
+                                     ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzApiManagementProduct], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.GetAzureApiManagementProduct
 
Get-AzApiManagementPolicy : Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext" value of type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Models.PsApiManagementContext".
At line:5 char:36
+ Get-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $Context
+                                    ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzApiManagementPolicy], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.ServiceManagement.Commands.GetAzureApiManagementPolicy
```

Comment: In the samples here, that is not how you use those cmdlets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementbackend?view=azps-9.0.1

Answer (score 2):

`-context` parameter accepts Instance of PsApiManagementContext.

You need to create the ApiManagementcontext using the `New-AzApiManagementContext` cmdlet and then pass the Context to the `-context` parameter to `Get-AzApiManagementBackend` cmdlet as shown below.

[image]

You can refer to this documentation for more information about these [powershell cmdlet for APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementbackend?view=azps-9.0.1)